# Java: Filling a buffer with words

Tags: java

Okay, so now i am dealing with this issue. I want to create a buffer with the size of 128 bytes and fill it with words from reading some files. I've already read those files and stored each word in an ArrayList. After buffer is filled with 16 words ( 8 bytes per word ), i have to create a new page at the end of the file. Then reset buffer and repeat until whole ArrayList is copied into the (binary) file.

How can i fill a buffer with these words? First time that im working with buffers and i could use some help! Thanks.

Code that i have( reading from files and storing)

```
try {
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
File dir = new File("path of folder that contains my files")

for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
        String [] tokens = line.split(",\\s+|\\s*\\\"\\s*|\\s+|\\.\\s*|\\s*\\:\\s*");
        for(int i=0; i<tokens.length(); i++)
        {  //Adding non-duplicates to arraylist
           if (!list.contains(tokens[i])  
           {
               list.add(tokens[i]);
           }
        }
    }
    Collections.Sort(list);
}
   }
     catch(Exception ex){}
```

Comment: That depends on what your buffer is. Just a byte array or something more complex like a `BufferedWriter`?

Comment: Why does your buffer care about word boundaries? And why buffer something that is already in memory?

Comment: @Thomas I dont know. How im supposed to know what? It says only buffer here!

Comment: Don't forget to close your BufferedReader.  You can use a Set instead of a List if you want unique Strings.

Comment: @Chris It's always a good idea to clarify what you actual task is before implementing it.

Comment: @radoh what do u mean?

Comment: @Chris well you said yourself `How im supposed to know what? It says only buffer here!`. How do you want to implement something without knowing precise specification? These articles may help you ask a good question - [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @radoh you are right! But my homework doesnt specify ! It says buffer! Nevertheless, i just want to see a complete example of a buffer to understand things! Thanks again!

Comment: If this is homework then pleasy say so. Real world problems are often more complex or have alterantive solutions while exercises are meant to teach _you_ a thing or two, so dependening on what it is our answers would be different.

Comment: @Thomas yes, it's an exercise!